# Are state initials supposed to be capitalized?

Tags: abbreviations

If I'm writing an article, and I mention a city and state, how do I write the state.

For example,

> "My friend is visiting from Los Angeles, CA."

OR

> "My friend is visiting from Los Angeles, Ca."

I know it's rather minuscule, but I would like to know.

Comment: Always capitalize both letters in the state abbreviation.

Comment: Do you specifically want to use the two-letter postal abbreviations? I ask because the actual abbreviation for California is "Calif." Also, as a note, unless you're talking about a city named Los Angeles that **isn't** in California... it's generally unnecessary to list the state at all.

Comment: I wouldn't bother mentioning the state. There is only one city in the USA with the name *Los Angeles*.  If you are going to go to the trouble of being so specific, then why not spell out *California*? Otherwise, the answer by @choster is a good one. Note that there is a **Capitol of Tx Highway** in Austin, Texas.

Answer (score 2):

State abbreviations are entirely a matter of style, and you should use the abbreviation and format dictated by your editor, house style, or preferred [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052).

First of all, consider whether an abbreviation is even necessary. In narrative text, for example, both the Associated Press Stylebook and the Chicago Manual of Style advise that the full name of the state be spelled out for clarity (except for the District of Columbia). CMOS favors this even when paired with a city; thus, *Lincoln, Nebraska* in CMOS; AP would formerly have advised  *Lincoln, Neb.*— only four characters shorter— but considering how obscure *Neb.* is to an international audience, [recent revisions](http://www.poynter.org/2014/ap-tells-reporters-spell-out-names-of-states-in-stories/249142/) advise the full name of the state be spelled out in body text.

Both AP and Chicago also provide [their own sets of state abbreviations](https://www.scribd.com/doc/58260290/State-Abbreviations-The-Difference-Between-AP-and-Chicago-Styles), which are based on traditional [U.S. postal abbreviations](https://about.usps.com/who-we-are/postal-history/state-abbreviations.pdf) in use prior to 1963 and GPO abbreviations in use prior to 1987. An American newspaper might print the dateline *Virginia Beach, Va.*, or notate Senator Lindsey Graham as *R-S.C.*, or caption a photo from *Dubuque, Iowa* (Alaska, Hawaii, Idaho, Iowa, Maine, Ohio, Texas, and Utah are never abbreviated in AP style).

APA style, for a counterexample, stipulates the use of the two-letter USPS ZIP Code abbreviations, which are always capitalized and never include periods. In AP or Chicago style, the postal abbreviation is only used for representing actual postal addresses, or in lists and tables where space is at a premium. But many organizations now favor these state abbreviations because they are short, consistent, and familiar to Americans, even if *ME* makes little sense to foreigners.

In your particular case, therefore, any of the following could be correct, though in the absence of other guidance, I would recommend the first:

> 1. My friend is visiting from Los Angeles, California.
> 2. My friend is visiting from Los Angeles, Calif.
> 3. My friend is visiting from Los Angeles, CA.

Wikipedia, naturally, provides a [comparative table of U.S. state abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_abbreviations), including some, like US Coast Guard vessel prefixes, that would be completely unfamiliar to a general audience.